# How to use regex-compat-tdfa instead of regex-compat

Tags: haskell, cabal

I need to use regular expression in Haskell, and I find `regex-compat-tdfa` and `regex-compat` are two possible choices. The previous one can support Unicode and more regex syntax. Unfortunately, they provide the same interface `Text.Regex`. So while I hope to use `regex-compat-tdfa`, GHC actually load `regex-compat`. I also try to use a `.cabal` file, but it also doesn't work. Is there any way to force GHC to use `regex-compat-tdfa`?

Comment: https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/school/to-infinity-and-beyond/pick-of-the-week/guide-to-ghc-extensions/basic-syntax-extensions#packageimports

Comment: I have tried `import qualified "regex-compat-tdfa" Text.Regex as Regex`, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Doesn't work how?

Comment: @sshashank124 For example `(\w+?)` will lead to an exception `unexpected "?" expecting empty () or anchor ^ or $, an atom, "|" or ")"`, which should not occur if `regex-compat-tdfa` were loaded.

Comment: And more explicitly, the callstack shows `error, called at lib/Text/Regex/TDFA/Common.hs:29:3 in rgx-tdf-1.3.1.0-e1a6a9ce:Text.Regex.TDFA.Common`.

Comment: The call stack does point at `TDFA`

Comment: Oh I see, the real problem is that I always use the regex syntax incorrectly (it seems `regex-tdfa` does not support `(\w+?)`).